# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'UserName'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'UserName'.
In view have 2 dropdownlists - for users and roles, after submitting i need to save role for choosen user. with role everything is ok, but trouble with user. i have list of users in list but i cant read slected for db. if use Html.TextBox("UserName") -it works, but admin will write username manually and it is not good.
I am not an expert in MVC so apreciate any help.
Controller:

```
    UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var user in db.UserProfiles.ToList())
        {
            SelectListItem li = new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = user.UserName,
                Text = user.UserName
            };
            items.Add(li);
        }

        ViewBag.UserName = items;

        return View(db.UserProfiles.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(string RoleName, string UserName)
    {

        SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
        ViewBag.Roles = list;
        return View();
    }
```

Model is of SimpleMembershipprovider, that is created with project.

View:

```
 @model IEnumerable<UserProfile>
 @Html.DropDownList("UserName", ViewBag.UserName as SelectList) - here mistake
```

What should i do to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the below code -

```
public ActionResult Index(string RoleName, string UserName)
{
    SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
    ViewBag.Roles = list;
    return View();
}
```

In above code you never initiated - `ViewBag.UserName`, but your view is expecting UserName property in ViewBag (you only initiated Roles). you initiate it and problem will be done.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
ViewBag.cityid = new SelectList(db.hr_pr_cities, "CityID", "Name");
```

and in view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("cityid", null, "Select City", null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserProfile>
@Html.DropDownList("UserName",new SelectList(ViewBag.UserName, "Value", "Text"))
```

Or change the type of your `UserName` to `SelectList` and then modify it here:

```
ViewBag.UserName = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
//instead of ViewBag.UserName = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

type of items is `List<SelectListItem>`, not `SelectList`.Try:

```
ViewBag.UserName as List<SelectListItem>
```